# doGet() and doPost() requests with a Google Web Script

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send information to a Google Web Script (specifically, send a JSON object containing info to write to a Google Sheet) but I'm having trouble sending GET and POST requests to my Google Script.

I'm using Node.js and the "request" module to send the requests, but I don't receive what my doGet() and doPost() functions are supposed to return, instead I receive very long HTML files that are unrelated, some of which indicate a 404 error.

As an example:

Node.js

```
var request = require('request');
request("https://script.google.com/macros/s/my-web-script/exec", function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Google Web Script:

```
function doGet(){
    textOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello World! Welcome to the 
                 web app.")
    return textOutput
}
```

I published the web script and made it accessible to anyone. I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that both your scripts work fine. So can you confirm the situation of deployed Web Apps, again? When you modify your script, Web Apps has to be redeployed as a new version.

How to deploy Web Apps is as follows.

- On the Script Editor
- Publish

  - Deploy as Web App

    - Create new Project version
    - At Execute the app as, select "your account"
    - At Who has access to the app, select "Anyone, even anonymous"
    - Click "Deploy"
    - Copy "Current web app URL"
    - Click "OK"

The `Current web app URL` is `https://script.google.com/macros/s/my-web-script/exec` in your script.

The detail information is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason I was deploying with the "User accessing web app" instead of myself. I changed it to running it as myself with anonymous access and everything works as intended. You are a lifesaver Tanaike!